# Ubuntu 14.04 Type 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ia32-libs-raring.list

Tags: 14.04, package-management, repository

I am rather new to using Linux OS. I would like to install new software to my newly installed Ubuntu OS. However, I am having trouble doing this. I get the following error while trying to download new software:

```
E: Type 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ia32-libs-raring.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` is up but your Ubuntu can't access it. I think this is a internet connection problem. Maybe you have a wrong DNS server or it isn't configured.

Comment: What's the release version? 16.0 ? 14.04 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your newly installed Ubuntu is not so newly installed. Probably the best thing to do is delete everything from /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ and then do apt update

Comment: do you have any tips for a new Linux user?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have installed `ia32-libs` package that no longer present as of Ubuntu 12.04 (precise), instead do a regular install you follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23194339) instruction from SO which suggest to do a tweak using 13.04 repositories.

However it's recommended that you remove `ia32-libs-raring.list` after install `ia32-libs`, I doubt you notice this part of answer:

> PS: In this way, you can install `ia32-libs`. However, we add the
>   source of 13.04 instead, so, there may be some unknown problem. After
>   installing `ia32-libs`, I recommend you to remove the
>   `ia32-libs-raring.list` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, and do `sudo
>   apt-get update`

Therefore, we'll remove that file:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ia32-libs-raring.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the above solution worked.